# ajax data dependent select

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send the value of a select to another select by ajax post , actually i get the value in idf but not in data , with `console.log(data)` i get all the html of the page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#specialite_id').change(function(){
   var idf=$(this).val();
    //var $id=$(this).serialize();
   event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       url : "index.php",
       type : "POST",
       data:'idf='+idf,
      datatype: "text",
       success : function(data){
           $('#section').html(data); 

          console.log(data);
       },

       error : function(){

       }
    });

});
})
</script>
```

in this is the html:

```
<select id="specialite_id">
    <?php   foreach( $rowAll as $row )
        { 

            ?>

<option value=<?php echo $row['id_specialite']; ?> > <?php echo $row['specialite']; ?> </option>

<?php 
}

?>
</select>


<select id="section">
     <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['idf'])){
    //$idf = $database->escape_string($_POST['idf']);

    $idf=$_POST['idf'];
     if(!empty($idf)){


    $sql3 = "SELECT section FROM section where id_specialite=:idf ";

        $stmt3 = $connexion->prepare($sql3);
        $stmt3->BindParam(':idf',$idf);
 $stmt3->execute( );
    $rowAll3 = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
foreach( $rowAll3 as $row3)
        { 


     ?> 

     <option > <?php echo $row3['section']; ?> </option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
```

why it doesn't work... anyone have an idea ?

Comment: you need a separate script for fetching this data, not just calling index.php. Otherwise yes of course it will return the whole page. You could prevent it by making if statement to say "if there's a POST value for "idf" then don't return _anything_ except for the `<option>` fields". But that's a bad separation of two different pieces of functionality, and if you put some more ajax on the page you'll just end up with spaghetti code in the end.

Comment: i'm just testing the ajax function ... i work with codeigniter and of curse i'll separate  .. but how to sepcify that i need just the value returned by the select ?

Comment: you can do it by using an `if` statement, as I mentioned above already.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't send the value to the same page so i created a new page "fetch.php" :

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT * from section where id_specialite =:idf ";

        $stmt2 = $connexion->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->BindParam(':idf',$_POST["idf"]);
        $stmt2->execute( );
        $rowAll2= $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        $output='<option value="">'.$_POST["idf"].'</option>';
    foreach( $rowAll2 as $row2)
        { 

          $output ='<option value="'.$row2["id_section"].'">'.$row2["section"].'</option>';
    echo $output;
     }
```

and i changed  the code of the script :

```
<select id="section" name="section">

     <option value=" "> selectioner section </option>

</select>



</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#specialite_id').change(function(){
   var idf=$(this).val();
  console.log(idf);
    $.ajax({
       url : "fetch.php",
       type : "POST",
       data:{idf:idf},
      datatype:"text",
       success:function(data){
           $('#section').html(data); 
           console.log(data);
       }


    });

});
})
</script>
```

it works !!

and for more informations :
https://youtu.be/T0Q0kEyEK_k

Answer (score -1):

I think you are passing json in wrong formate, try following:

```
  data:"{'idf':"+idf+"}",
```

Comment: this will just produce a string as the post variable, which won't work, especially as the content type isn't set to JSON and the server isn't trying to decode JSON.